# How does anonymous block forwarding (&block) work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I'm using `around_action` to set the timezone of the Rails application temporarily to the timezone selected by the current user. My code looks like this:

```
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user

private

def set_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

My question is, what does `&block` represent in this context?

My understanding is that it represents the duration of time we want to set the timezone to the user's timezone before we set it back to the default for the application.

In this case is that the duration of the `yield`?

Comment: `block` is not a duration of time, it's a [proc](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Proc.html) holding the controller's code for that request. By passing the block along to `Time.use_zone`, the code gets executed within the given timezone. (which is restored afterwards)

Comment: Thanks for this @Stefan this explains it really clearly and is what I assumed was happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone :

> `use_zone(time_zone)`
>
> Allows override of Time.zone locally inside supplied block; resets Time.zone to existing value when done.
>
> ```
> # File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb, line 61
> def use_zone(time_zone)
>   new_zone = find_zone!(time_zone)
>   begin
>     old_zone, ::Time.zone = ::Time.zone, new_zone
>     yield
>   ensure
>     ::Time.zone = old_zone
>   end
> end
> ```

So the change of the time zone is visible only inside the block you pass to this method.

Take a look:

```rb
    Time.zone = "London"

    Time.use_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)") do
      puts Time.zone
    end

    puts Time.zone
```

And the output is:

```
(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) # inside the block
(GMT+00:00) London # outside
```